# The constructor MapView(Context, GoogleMapOptions) is undefined

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to create a `MapView` on Android using options but doesn't work because the compiler doesn't recognize **the constructor `MapView(Context, GoogleMapOptions)`**. But, this constructor does exist according to [the API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView#public-constructors).

This is the code in question:

```
private static Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //some code...
    context = getApplicationContext();

    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
            options.mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
            .compassEnabled(false)
            .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
            .tiltGesturesEnabled(false);

    MapView mapView = new MapView(context, options);

    //...
    }
```

Comment: Try just giving 'this' if you're in an activity anyway.

Comment: Doesn't work. Actually, the problem is with the GoogleMapOptions. Eclipse says : constructor MapView(DisplayMapsActivity, GoogleMapOptions) is undefined.

Comment: could you post the full error log?

Comment: That's a ctor for Maps V2 MapView. You probably already know that, since your using GoogleMapOptions and so on, but just in case, make sure your MapView import is from V2 (com.google.android.gms, not com.google.android.maps). Posting the full stack trace would clear that up.

Comment: My bad! I'm using Maps V1.
Thanks everyone, especially Charlie...